# API to list dlls used by a process and store the results in a txt file?

Tags: cmd, process, process-explorer

Is there any APIs that I can use to get the dll list used by a process and store the dll list retrieved into a txt file?

Tool should be invoked from the command line.

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls)

Comment: Can I redirect the console output of ListDll to a txt file? If yes how?